# Erro: Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4(kitkat); current using API 16

Tags: java, android, android-eclipse

Usando um `switch case` com uma *string*.

O Eclipse acusou erro e ofereceu trocar para `compiling 1.7`.

Aceitei, agora dá erro e não consigo voltar.

Como resolvo isso?

[image: SS]

Quero modificar o nível da linguagem para 1.6, mas não acho isso em nenhum lugar.

Comment: A APi 16 é para o Android IceCream Sandwich. Você está tentando compilar para o KitKat. Verifique no `AndroidManifest` se o `targetSdkVersion`. está compatível com o SDK que você tem instalado

Comment: o problema não é esse, isso está certinho, é o nível da linguagem, eu subi ele sem querer e não consigo voltar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nível da linguagem que você está usando (Java 1.7) está disponível a partir do Kit Kat.

Se você quiser continuar utilizando este nível de linguagem, você deve alterar no manifesto para o SDK 19.

Caso contrário, altere o nível da linguagem para 1.6.

Comment: sim, isso eu entendi, quero modificar o nível da linguagem para 1.6, mas não acho isso em nenhum lugar.
como faço?

Comment: Tenta isso:
In project properties->Java Build Path/Libraries tab make sure you have JRE System Library 6 ennvironment

Comment: Clique botão direito no `projeto > propriedades > Java Compiler > Compiler Compilance level `